# Selenium findElement(By.CSS_SELECTOR)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this button on the page:

```
<button type="submit" class="sc-pjTqr dzmlqP">Continue</button>`
```

I checked the documentation and StackOverflow answers and it seems to me that the solution should be:

```
continue = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.sc-pjTqr.dzmlqP")
```

But does not work.

I searched for solutions, but I didn't understand. Why?

Comment: Can you confirm the URL?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The url where this button can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *classnames* i.e. `sc-pjTqr`, `dzmlqP` are dynamically generated and is bound to chage sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

To identify the element with text as **Continue** you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  continue = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Continue']")
  ```

Ideally to identify the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  continue = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Continue']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The OP doesn't confirm the url where this button lives, so I can test the solution:

```
button = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "sc-pjTqr")))
```

There are other ways as well.